# Why is my comparison failing?

Tags: c#

```
 if (dgv.Rows.Count.ToString() == "2")
```

the above code is working perfectly but when i want to give it limit and change it to the following:

```
if (dgv.Rows.Count.ToString() <= "2")
```

it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your question has nothing to do with either WPF or Datagrid, just plain c#. I edited it accordingly.

Comment: Comparing as a string, when you are actually trying to interpret the values as integers usually does not produce what you think. Lookup "natural sort order" to understand why.

Comment: Thanks Roel i appreciate your revision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant use greater than on strings. Try:

```
if (dgv.Rows.Count <= 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd assume that `.Count` returns a number, so I'd expect the code to be

```
if (dgv.Rows.Count == 2) 
if (dgv.Rows.Count <= 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

This "2" is a string. So, it just compares whether the value is equal or not. Therefore, the first one works.

For second condition, it does not know how to do a compare. You will have to convert this "2" to Int and then compare.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are misunderstanding the problem. you should not do a `Tostring` at all when comparing values: you are comparing `string`s, and not actual numbers (`int`). Also, you cannot do the `<=` operation on strings.

Update your code to

```
if (dgv.Rows.Count <= 2)
```

and all should be good.

Answer (score 1):

you are comparing strings and not acctuall numeric values

What you want to compare in your second if statement is this: "2" <= "2"

What you should do is: 2 <= 2

like this:

```
if (dgv.Rows.Count <= 2)
```